# Set UIViewController title by property or delegate method reference

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, properties, delegates

I am making an app that deals with **categories** and **products**. A category has subcategories which may have further subcategories or products. The main categories have their own slide out controller. All subcategories of a main category appear in their own controller.

For every category that is selected (represented by a *UITableViewCell* in a *UITableView*) a call to a web service is made which returns a json with a list of its subcategories or products. To track the download progress of these items, a protocol is declared with the following methods:

```
@protocol ItemsRetrievalDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)retrievingItems;
- (void)didRetrieveItems:(NSDictionary *)items;
- (void)failedToRetrieveItemsWithError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

Every view controller that presents subcategories or products implements this protocol.

For every group of subcategories I need to display a **title** named with the name of their **parent category**. To that end, I have declared a property named `parentCategory`. Now for every selection of a category I can set this property for the next view controller title.

But is this solution the ideal one from a design point of view? Would it be better to refactor the `retrievingItems` method of the protocol to:

```
- (void)retrievingItemsForCategory:(Category *)aCategory;
```

and set the parent category title for the view controller during the retrieval of subcategories or products? Bear in mind that a subcategory is not "aware" of its parent.

Which of the two solutions would you consider best/cleaner?

Thanks.

Comment: Better to refactor, like you've suggested. However, I don't understand how the delegate can't already be aware of the category. If the delegate is a vc at the bottom of navigation stack, it makes an ItemsRetrival vc and pushes it on, but how does that ItemsRetrieval vc know what category to query on?

Comment: The delegate is not at the bottom of the navigation stack at least in the beginning. The query for the sub categories is placed by the controller containing the parent category. The new controller that acts as a delegate for the retrieval process and is pushed on the stack has no knowledge of which the parent category is.

Comment: If you are talking on a controller level, the navigation controller keeps track of what is on its stack. If on an entity design level, you are saying that the child should be aware of its parent. However, the json for the subcategory or product does not include any fields for its parent. To which of the 2 are you referring?

Comment: Controller level, JSON can't be helped.

Comment: Is there a place where parent view controller awareness by the child (not in containment but in navigation controller succession) is documented as a best practice? I am currently ignorant of the fact...